# How can I use Navigation on MAUI in a no-shell app?

Tags: c#, navigation, maui

I'm creating a simple app with MAUI but due to some problems with the shell not rendering properly in Android and Windows I decided to go "shell-less".

There are a lot of blogs and posts showing how to use the Navigation instance for non-shell navigation. Example:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage1());
```

This works fine from the Page.cs but I can't do such call from the ModelView.cs because the Navigation thingy is part of the ContentPage implementation. The shell is available in ModelViews and we can do this:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..?update=true");
```

But how can I navigate from ModelView instead of from Page (without shell)?

Comment: `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation`

Comment: A single-liner answer. Thanks! It solved perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As jason said, you can use the `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation` directly in the viewmodel.

In addition, you can also pass the Page's Navigation to the viewmodel and then use it. Such as:

In the viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel : ObseervableObject
{
    public INavigation Navigation { get; set;}

    public MyViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
    }
}
```

And in the page.cs:

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       BindingContext = new MyViewModel(Navigation);
    }
}
```

And then you can use the `Navigation` in the viewmodel.